# possible to share views across multiple mvc 3 projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, partial-views

I am building several different asp.net mvc 3 web projects all under one solution.  I'd like to be able to utilize a few views across all of those projects as they're all going to be displaying the same thing on 2 or 3 different pages (with some custom stuff plugged in per the application).

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only thing I can think of is to compile your cshtml into a separate assembly (assuming you are using RAZOR). See [here](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking I've not seen many examples of multi project ASP.NET MVC solutions. Because it kinda doesn't make sense. It complicates things, it disregards `areas`, which could possibly be used to get the same kind of experience but are far better option that multiple MVC projects. Then there's the question whether the 3 projects have so much in common that they really should all be in one solution. What kind of MVC applications do you actually have? What do they do? Most sample solutions online are single MVC project and multiple class library projects.

Now to the actual question..I recently found myself doing something similar, actually I didn't have multiple projects in one solution but I had different standalone projects that would all benefit from using the Views from one single, we could say the "master" project. I ended up creating `Nuget` package for it. I actually also injected other stuff into the package (scripts, styles, images, etc) but you could use it for Views only too. Then you just add the package to the next project and it inserts the files in the package into destination project. What I'm trying to say is, your package doesn't necessarily have to contain code.

I won't go into details here but you should look into it.

Comment: Enterprise level solutions often require SOA services to be separated onto different sub domains within the same product. In those cases, you do have separate projects that share common libraries and can include common layouts.